# UIImagePickerController dismiss crashes

Tags: xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I ran into trouble implementing standard camera function in Xcode 11.3. The app crashes when I click the "Use Photo" button. Click the "Retake" button works fine.

```
@IBAction func onPhotoButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
{
    imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true) // crashes on this line!
    imageView.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
}
```

The crash occurs on the .dismiss line.
error is " Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value:"

I reviewed the previous postings on similar issues and none seems to solve this problem.

Comment: worked when change the offending line to 
       picker.dismiss(animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

worked when change the offending line to

```
 picker.dismiss(animated: true)
```